# Is it possible to use tailwind css in my flask app?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, tailwind-css

Is it possible to use **Tailwind CSS** in my **Flask app** without **npm** or **node.js** ?

- If it's possible then can someone guide me how to do it ?
- Or If not then is there any alternative for it in Flask - Python ?

Comment: And what is preventing you from using it?

Comment: I'm not much familiar with node.js  But now i have to think about it !!

Comment: a few hello-world projects can be found via github.
`https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=tailwind+flask&s=stars&type=Repositories`

Answer (score 3):

You can use Tailwind CSS with Flask the same way you use it with any framework (or even for a static website with plain HTML and CSS). But installing it with npm or yarn is the best and cleanest way of doing it, there isn't a lot of configuration required you just need to init your project with node or yarn `npm init` or `yarn init` and then follow the steps in the [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation).

Alternativelly if you really don't want to use npm, you can use the "Play CDN" functionality (it will work as well with flask) but this isn't recommended for production, you just need to add this line in your `<head>` tag

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
```

Comment: After adopting the documentation I now have the problem, that I need to run `npx tailwindcss build -i ./static/src/styles.css -o ./static/css/main.css` any time  I'm editing tailwind classes in my styles css. How can I automatically generate the current css needed and also allow HTML inline class styling ?

Comment: @Ndrslmpk you can add --watch to the end of that command to watch the styles.css file for changes and auto-rebuild

Answer (score 1):

It's possible when you use the tailwind play cdn method. But using the npm/yarn method to get tailwind css up and running in your flask project is, I think better. You don't also really need to know node.js to achieve this. All you need is the npm which comes packaged with node to install tailwind css and all of it must have files in your Flask project.

Answer (score 0):

I know your question is specifically for tailwind .. and there is an alpha flask-tailwind project but I haven't tinkered with it. There is a robust Flask-Boostrap4 module that is worth a look.